# How to refresh my csv file every 10 minutes, Flask, Python

Tags: python, csv, flask, time

I'm trying to create a 'simple' website, about betting.

- A user enters the amount of money he wants to convert.
- The website gives him the best games to bet on, and the stakes on each of the bets.
  [Website's home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymhPj.png)

I'm implementing this website in Python, with Flask. I already created the code that scraps the data from the betting site, and that creates a CSV file out of it.

My concern is : how can I automaticaly refresh my csv file every 10 minutes, no regard if there is a request made or not ?

This is my Flask file for creating the app :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
import time
import threading

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.config['SECRET_KEY']="abcjzllkk"
   
   
   from .views import views
   from .auth import auth
   
   app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
   app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/")
   
   return app
```

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: ...there really isn't any reason to write it out to a file. You even already have a database? Just modify your scraper code to write it to the db and run it in a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), then read from the database when you get a request. Probably worth noting that doing this in the first place probably violates the TOS for the betting site...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is make a separate process to monitor and scrape the CSV on a set schedule, and the web server should be a completely separate process which just reads the result CSV file.

Check out Python Celery, APScheduler or even a simple cron job to automate your scraper.

The only thing to keep track of is file locking for the very miniscule time that the CSV is being updated. You can probable get around that using a database since you already have SQLAlchemy you could use SQLite, but honestly on a low traffic site you shouldn't have any problems and it's faster for someone to reload or try twice than do anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically refresh your CSV file every 10 minutes, you can utilize a separate thread that runs in the background, triggering the refresh process independently of user requests. You can achieve this by adding the threading module in Python.

```
from flask import Flask
import threading
import time

# Function to refresh the CSV file
def refresh_csv_file():
    while True:
        # Your code to refresh the CSV file goes here
        # This could involve scraping data and updating the CSV file
        print("Refreshing CSV file...")
        
        # Simulating the wait for 10 minutes before the next refresh
        time.sleep(600)  # 600 seconds = 10 minutes

# Function to create the Flask app
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "abcjzllkk"

    # Your other configurations, blueprints, etc.
    # ...

    # Start the thread for refreshing the CSV file
    refresh_thread = threading.Thread(target=refresh_csv_file)
    refresh_thread.daemon = True  # Set as daemon so it stops when the main app stops
    refresh_thread.start()

    return app
```